# How do I select a tag with text between the tag and it's parent tag?

Tags: jquery, css

How can I distinguish, using CSS, between a tag that, were it and its contents to be deleted, would leave its parent tag empty? I don't actually want to delete it, I just want to treat it differently.

For example, given the following sample code:

```
<div><a>test one</a></div>
<div>My <a>test two</a></div>
<div>My <a>test three</a> and <a>test four</a> text</div>
<div><a>Test five</a> text</div>
<div>My <a>test six</a> text</div>
```

The following CSS:

```
a:only-child { color: #668899; }
```

selects for all but tests three and four.

```
a:not(only-child) { color: #668899; }
```

selects for all, but I'd expect it to select **only** tests three and four.

How do I select all tests **except** test one using only CSS?

If I can't style only tests two through six with only CSS, can I style them with jQuery? If so, how?

Comment: If you add a colon in front of the only-child it works (tested in Chrome)
`a:not(:only-child) { color: #668899; }` The reason why it was not working before was due to :not() expecting a selector, and it could not find an **ELEMENT** named "only-child" (i.e no element named <only-child></only-child>).

Comment: Will your DOM always look like this? What is special about "test one"? would you be willing to just add an id to the desired element?

Answer (score 2):

This probably isn't the most efficient solution, but it works — compare the text content of each `<a>` element with the text content of its parent. If they're the same, then apply a different style:

```js
$('div a').each(function(){
  if ($(this).text()===$(this).parent().text()) {
    $(this).addClass('onlyChild');
  }
});
```

```css
.onlyChild { color: #668899; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><a>test one</a></div>
<div>My <a>test two</a></div>
<div>My <a>test three</a> and <a>test four</a> text</div>
<div><a>Test five</a> text</div>
<div>My <a>test six</a> text</div>
```

Comment: Thank you; that's very helpful. Do I correctly presume I could flip that to style tests two through six but not test one by changing the == to != instead? (I probably would want to find a different class name.)

Comment: Yes, just change `==` to `!=` (actually this only works properly if you use `addClass()` instead of `toggleClass()`. I'll update the answer.)

Comment: Thank you for the update. And my editor wants me to make that === or !==

Comment: @CharlesBelov Your editor makes good suggestions! I've edited the answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Right now your rule is looking for a element called `only-child`

Use this selector rule

`a:not(:only-child) { color: #668899; }`

Sample demo

```css
a:not(:only-child) { color: red; }
```

```html
<div><a>test one</a></div>
<div>My <a>test two</a></div>
<div>My <a>test three</a> and <a>test four</a> text</div>
<div><a>Test five</a> text</div>
<div>My <a>test six</a> text</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to select anything.